# Preparing HDF5 data to create scikit ML models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hdf5

I need to create machine learning models to simulate some data processing tasks. The data in question is several radar bands used to calculate wind speeds. The interaction of these bands is what defines how speed is calculated. Because of the polarization of the bands, I end up with 12 input Pandas Dataframes corresponding to one output frame which is the 'real' value of the wind speeds. I am trying to create an SVM model. I feel like I can optimize the data a bit but am having some efficiency issues and Data Conversion Warnings that I don't know how to fix. The code seems to output with other models like Linear Regression and SGD by taking a while but SVM seems like it gets stuck modelling for hours. Summary of the code is  bellow.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py                  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.svm import SVR

f1 = h5py.File(inputFile,"r") 
f2 = h5py.File(trainingFile,"r")
G35V   = f1['Brightness Temperature (36.5GHz,V)']
G35H   = f1['Brightness Temperature (36.5GHz,H)']

G6V = f1['Brightness Temperature (6.9GHz,V)']
G6H = f1['Brightness Temperature (6.9GHz,H)']

G7H = f1['Brightness Temperature (7.3GHz,H)']
G7V = f1['Brightness Temperature (7.3GHz,V)']

G10H = f1['Brightness Temperature (10.7GHz,H)']
G10V = f1['Brightness Temperature (10.7GHz,V)']

G18H = f1['Brightness Temperature (18.7GHz,H)']
G18V = f1['Brightness Temperature (18.7GHz,V)']

G23H = f1['Brightness Temperature (23.8GHz,H)']
G23V = f1['Brightness Temperature (23.8GHz,V)']

GeoD = f2['Geophysical Data']
GeoData = np.ndarray(shape=GeoD.shape,dtype=int)
GeoD.read_direct(GeoData)
#remove dimension to match inputs
GeoData = GeoData[:,:,0]

inputDataframe = pd.DataFrame({'G35H':np.asarray(G35H).flatten(), 'G35V':np.asarray(G35V).flatten(), 'G6V':np.asarray(G6V).flatten(), 'G6H':np.asarray(G6H).flatten(), 'G7V':np.asarray(G7V).flatten(),'G7H':np.asarray(G7H).flatten(), 'G10V':np.asarray(G10V).flatten(),'G10H':np.asarray(G10H).flatten(),'G18V':np.asarray(G18V).flatten(),'G18H':np.asarray(G18H).flatten(), 'G23V':np.asarray(G23V).flatten(),'G23H':np.asarray(G23H).flatten() }  )

outputDataframe = pd.DataFrame({'GeoData': np.asarray(GeoData).flatten()})
f1.close()
f2.close()
SVM = SVR()
SVM.fit(inputDataframe , outputDataframe)
```

Once created the model will be passed to another method to create an output prediction with the following loop and a different input file:

```
for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(o_gp):
    o_gp[idx] = SVM.predict([[G35H[idx] ,G35V[idx],G6V[idx] ,G6H[idx] ,G7V[idx] ,G7H[idx] ,G10V[idx],G10H[idx],G18V[idx] ,G18H[idx] , G23V[idx], G23H[idx] ]])
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I noticed you declared variables `lon`, `lat` and `ScanIn`, but don't use them. Is that intended, or an oversight? Also, `GeoData` is referenced in the declaration for `outputDataframe`, but I don't see it in your code. Is that a copy/paste error when you wrote the post?

Comment: @kcw78 My bad. Copy/paste error and data prep for other parts of code. Edited it to reflect the missing bits and removed the extra variables.

Comment: What *exactly* is your issue and your *question*?

Comment: @desertnaut The prediction for loop at the end feels jury rigged since as far as I can tell you're not supposed to do that in python. Is there a way to do that using matrix operations? I know predict() takes array-likes as an argument but cant seem to get it to work otherwise